# Firefox ignores media.autoplay.default since recent upgrade to 66.0.1

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, firefox, video

The `media.autoplay.default` setting (value=1) in `about:config` used to prevent video/media from playing automatically on loading a page with such content present.

Since the recent (2019-03-25) upgrade to `66.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` video just plays automatically regardless of this setting.

I have a no flash/java environment, so we're just talking HTML5 here.

There are other media.autoplay options available, but setting them doesn't seem to fix the problem completely and breaks other aspects of the browser.

Does anyone know a fix to stop media autoplay in Firefox?

Comment: I believe FF 66 now auto blocks But only videos that have sound enabled. So here on sites that mute their videos  they play (without sound) On sites that have audio enabled the autoplay is blocked. Pretty easy to see on for instance CNN which has sound enabled.

Answer (score 0):

media.autoplay.default;1
media.autoplay.block-webaudio;true
media.autoplay.allow-muted;false

And in 66+, also add:  media.autoplay.enabled.user-gestures-needed;false